# jQuery spinner only format the number after spin

Tags: jquery, format, jquery-ui-spinner

I'm trying to create a spinner that shows a formatted float. The formatter only works after spin event. Is there any way to format it on stop event?

This is my code:

```
<script src="/files/recursos/globalize/lib/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="/files/recursos/globalize/lib/cultures/globalize.cultures.js"></script>
<script src="/files/recursos/globalize/lib/cultures/globalize.culture.es.js"></script>

<script>

$( "#input_importe" ).spinner({
    step: 0.01,
    culture: "es",
    numberFormat: "n2",
    min: 0
});

//EVENTS
$( "#input_importe" ).spinner({
  spin: function( event, ui ) {
      console.log("SPIN");
      $( "#input_importe" ).spinner("value", ui.value); 
  },
  stop: function( event, ui ) {   
      current = $( "#spinner" ).spinner( "value");
      console.log('STOP ' + current);
      $( "#spinner" ).spinner( "value", current );
  }
});
```

I'm using Globalize.js (v 0.1.1) and it works correctly when I use the spin, but I need to format the value when I put it manually in the input box (on stop event).

FE: 1.005,23

Any ideas?, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the following command in order to refresh the culture and apply the appropriate format:
**$(this).spinner( "option", "culture", "es");**